# Sort entityQuery by date published

Tags: 8, entities

I'm attempting to perform a query to retrieve only the three most recent nodes of a certain content type.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type', 'blog_post')
    ->sort('field');
$nids = $query->execute();
```

I understand that I can use sort to specify the field I want the results to be sorted by. But how would I sort by the dates the nodes were published?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

'created' was the field.
I was able to find this by looking at the fields being used in Core\Modules\node\src\Entity\Node.php

Comment: Note that created is not the date when the node was *published*, it is when the node was created. That can but most not be the same. Drupal by default doesn't store a publication date.

Comment: However, this is the value shown and editable in the "Authored on" field.

Answer (score 23):

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
                ->condition('status', 1) 
                ->sort('created' , 'DESC');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('status', 1) 
    ->sort('changed' , 'DESC'); 

//Available fields
public function fields() {
  $fields = array(
    'nid' => $this
      ->t('Node ID'),
    'type' => $this
      ->t('Type'),
    'title' => $this
      ->t('Title'),
    'body' => $this
      ->t('Body'),
    'format' => $this
      ->t('Format'),
    'teaser' => $this
      ->t('Teaser'),
    'node_uid' => $this
      ->t('Node authored by (uid)'),
    'revision_uid' => $this
      ->t('Revision authored by (uid)'),
    'created' => $this
      ->t('Created timestamp'),
    'changed' => $this
      ->t('Modified timestamp'),
    'status' => $this
      ->t('Published'),
    'promote' => $this
      ->t('Promoted to front page'),
    'sticky' => $this
      ->t('Sticky at top of lists'),
    'revision' => $this
      ->t('Create new revision'),
    'language' => $this
      ->t('Language (fr, en, ...)'),
    'tnid' => $this
      ->t('The translation set id for this node'),
    'timestamp' => $this
      ->t('The timestamp the latest revision of this node was created.'),
  );
  return $fields;
}
```

> [Source](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!src!Plugin!migrate!source!d6!Node.php/function/Node::fields/8.2.x)