# Sort with entityTypeManager

Tags: 8, entities

I'm running an app where I am searching for every nodes of a given content type.

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getListBuilder('node')
  ->getStorage()
  ->loadByProperties([
    'type' => 'courses',
    'status' => 1,
]);
```

I'm searching for a way to sort the results among a custom field of my nodes.

EDIT:
I do not understand what's going on.
Thanks to @4k4, I wrote this query:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getListBuilder('node')
    ->getStorage()
    ->getQuery();
$query->condition('type', 'post');
$query->condition('status', 1);
$query->condition('field_category', $k);
$query->sort('field_ordering', 'ASC');

$nids = $query->execute();
$nids = Node::loadMultiple($nids);
```

A `var_dump` on `$r[1]` prints nothing. Same for `$r[2]`. But $results contains my results. What's going on ?
The sorting doesn't work by the way.

Comment: use entityQuery, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205075/sort-entityquery-by-date-published

Comment: I am working on 8.4 and entityQuery is deprecated since 8.3.

Comment: No, entityQuery is not deprecated, or do you mean how to get to it? You know if you inject entityTypeManager you can get entityQuery from it as well?

Comment: Did I miss-read this post ? https://www.drupal.org/node/2389335 
Could you provide me a snippet using entityQuery that joins with nodes custom fields tables ? I tried entityQueryAggregate but it won't work. I am totally lost here.

Comment: Yes, you are, loadByProperties was never meant to be a replacement for entityQuery, it is a shortcut to it for simple searches without sorting or other advanced things. See the answer how to sort with entityQuery in D8.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2849874) says if you have entityTypeManager injected, use

```
$query = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->getQuery();
```

For non-OOP code, `$query = \Drupal::entityQuery();` is not deprecated and can still be used.

The linked example for sorting an entity query by using `$query`:

```
$query->condition('type', 'blog_post')
  ->sort('field', 'DESC');
$nids = $query->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you this helps. However, I need to add a condition on a custom field (field_test) and it seems the joins aren't made in this request.

Comment: Is sorting working now? - For a condition on a field, this would be a separate issue. Normally you can use all fields. If not, ask another question and tell what is special about the custom field so that is doesn't work.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: Please don't post this amount of code not directly connected to the question.

Comment: I found my error. I was doing a foreach on my table and reindexing my output array with the node key (so the ID). I turned the keys to strings and it works ! Thanks.